# How to check from google analytics module if user gave permission for cookies on eu-cookie-compliance module

Tags: drupal

So I have google analytics module and eu-cookie-compliance module, both working fine. Now I'm trying to disable google analytics if user didn't give permission for cookies on eu-cokie-compliance. I know that cookie module has javascript function

```
Drupal.eu_cookie_compliance.hasAgreed()
```

But I have to check that from php code in google analytics. So when page first load google analytics will be disabled.

Any ideas how to make it work?

```
<?php 
$cookie=$_COOKIE['cookie-agreed-sl'];
if($cookie==1 || $cookie==2)return true;
else return false;

?>
```

So i added that code to google analytics code but it always returnss false so google analytics cookie is newer set. I tried that code in some php file and there it works. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eu_cookie_compliance logic can be found in the javascript file: [js/eu_cookie_compliance.js](http://drupalcode.org/project/eu-cookie-compliance.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/js/eu_cookie_compliance.js) contains `eu_cookie_compliance_get_settings`:

```
Drupal.eu_cookie_compliance.setStatus = function(status) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 100);
    document.cookie = "cookie-agreed-"+Drupal.settings.eu_cookie_compliance.popup_language + "="+status+";expires=" + date.toUTCString() + ";path=" + Drupal.settings.basePath;
}
```

So you have to get this cookie using php.

Comment: Did you check which cookies where set?

Comment: wow, i found out that this code is called only once per page. So i needed to go to another page to activate google analytics. And attacat cookie tool didnt find it, so now i tried printing out all cookies and i can see that there is analytics too. So thanks!